# Why does a CALayer's transform3D's m34 need to be modified before applying the rotate transform?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, calayer

The following code can make a ***perspective*** rotation transform for a layer:

```
CATransform3D transform3DFoo = CATransform3DIdentity;

transform3DFoo.m34 = -1.0 / 1000;

transform3DFoo = CATransform3DRotate(transform3DFoo, M_PI / 4, 1, 0, 0);
```

However, if the two lines are reversed:

```
CATransform3D transform3DFoo = CATransform3DIdentity;

transform3DFoo = CATransform3DRotate(transform3DFoo, M_PI / 4, 1, 0, 0);

transform3DFoo.m34 = -1.0 / 1000;
```

then the perspective is gone.  Now it is orthographic (no perspective).  Does someone who is familiar with perspective know why the reason?

---

**Update:**

```
// First Identity and then transform3DFoo.m34 = -1.0 / 1000; is done

1.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000 
0.00000     1.00000     0.00000     0.00000 
0.00000     0.00000     1.00000    -0.00100 
0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     1.00000 

// and then CATransform3DRotate(transform3DFoo, M_PI / 4, 1, 0, 0);

1.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000 
0.00000     0.70711     0.70711    -0.00071 
0.00000    -0.70711     0.70711    -0.00071 
0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     1.00000 

// Now start with Identity and only the Rotate statement is done:

1.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000 
0.00000     0.70711     0.70711     0.00000 
0.00000    -0.70711     0.70711     0.00000 
0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     1.00000 

// and then transform3DFoo.m34 = -1.0 / 1000; is done

1.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000 
0.00000     0.70711     0.70711     0.00000 
0.00000    -0.70711     0.70711    -0.00100 
0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     1.00000
```

(the tag of "OpenGL" is added because it probably is the same principle in OpenGL)

Comment: I've never heard the term _perspective rotation_ before. Please provide the transformations in both cases; ahem, did you accidently swap the two code snippets? I'd expect the second one to be a perspective transform.

Comment: You mean you want the values in those 2 matrices?

Comment: Yes; and again: did you swap the code snippets? Never done anything with CA before, I'm currently assuming that CA multiplies vectors from the left to matrices.

Comment: because a book mentioned `transform3DFoo.m34 = -1.0 / 1000;` but never explain the importance of any order, so I found that if it is sample 2, then it won't work

Comment: the matrices are printed in the update in the original question

Comment: m34 is the "lens length".  Choose a small value (1/10) and it will as if you are very close to the rotating object.  Choose a large value (1/10000) and it will be as if you are very far away.  In answer to your question, of course applying CATransform3DRotate actually ***changes the matrix***.  Reversing the order of operations with matrices is of course totally different; you get completely different results.

Answer (score 6):

Setting `m34` first is equivalent to rotating first and then projecting. Setting `m34` last is roughly equivalent to projecting first and then rotating. As the input coordinates have z=0, projecting first won't do anything.

To see why this is, you need to understand a little about how transform matrices work.

I believe that in CA positions are transformed by a transform matrix `M` by doing:

```
[x y z w] = [x y z w] * M
```

(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

Multiplying two transform matrices together is equivalent to concatenating the transforms. The transform/matrix on the left happens first. It's pretty easy to see why this is:

```
[x y z w] * (LEFT * RIGHT) = ([x y z w] * LEFT) * RIGHT
```

Most (all?) of the CA transform functions (eg `CATransform3DRotate`) just premultiply your transform matrix by another aptly constructed matrix, eg:

```
M = ROTATE * M
```

Setting `m34` is roughly equivalent to premultiplying by a projection matrix, that is:

```
M = PROJ * M
```

(where `PROJ` is the projection matrix -- an identity matrix but with `m34` set)

This isn't entirely true (which is why I keep saying roughly) -- it only works if `M` has some 0s and 1s in the right places. Basically, in the general case, just setting `m34` is a nonsense thing to do -- the right thing to do is to multiply by a projection matrix.

Anyway, if you put all that together you should be able to see why what I said in the first paragraph is true (assuming I haven't made any mistakes :)

Comment: Say @dave, you may have an angle on this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364831/catransform3didentity-yaw-around-any-axis-not-just-x-0  Cheers